# ArgumentNullException on System.Windows.Automation when trying to print open tabs in Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, tabs

This code should be working, at least it does for someone else but I keep getting the same `ArgumentNullException was unhandled` error? What could be the problem?

The app is supposed to print out the open tabs in google chrome.Try to run it and see if it works for you.

I imported `UIAtomationClient.dll` and `UIAutomationTypes.dll`

```
 using System.Windows.Automation;
...
    Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
                if (procsChrome.Length <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Chrome is not running");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (Process proc in procsChrome)
                    {
                        // the chrome process must have a window 
                        if (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        // to find the tabs we first need to locate something reliable - the 'New Tab' button 
                        AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                        Condition condNewTab = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "New Tab");
                        AutomationElement elmNewTab = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, condNewTab);

                        // get the tabstrip by getting the parent of the 'new tab' button 
                        TreeWalker treewalker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
                        AutomationElement elmTabStrip = treewalker.GetParent(elmNewTab); // <- Error on this line

                        // loop through all the tabs and get the names which is the page title 
                        Condition condTabItem = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TabItem);
                        foreach (AutomationElement tabitem in elmTabStrip.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, condTabItem))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(tabitem.Current.Name);
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: By the exception, you should debug to see why `elmNewTab` is null. (ArgumentNullException)

Comment: Why the vote down? I don't see where this question is a bad question. Can you downvoters please explain?

Comment: @r1verside I haven't downvoted the question myself, but as far as titles go, "Code should work but it doesn't" is one of the worst I've seen around here. I've suggested a new one, it's in the edit queue now. Hopefully someone will approve it. The question itself seems ok to me.

Comment: @JoséLuis Yeah the title is not very descriptive, didn't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this Automation thing but here's working

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Automation;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
            if (procsChrome.Length <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Chrome is not running");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Process proc in procsChrome)
                {
                    // the chrome process must have a window 
                    if (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // to find the tabs we first need to locate something reliable - the 'New Tab' button 
                    AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                    Condition condTabs = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button);
                    //Condition condNewTab = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "new tab");
                    AutomationElementCollection col = root.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, condTabs);
                    AutomationElement elmNewTab = col[4]; // allways the position 4 is new tab button

                    // get the tabstrip by getting the parent of the 'new tab' button 
                    TreeWalker treewalker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
                    AutomationElement elmTabStrip = treewalker.GetParent(elmNewTab); // <- Error on this line

                   // loop through all the tabs and get the names which is the page title 
                    Condition condTabItem = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TabItem);
                    foreach (AutomationElement tabitem in elmTabStrip.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, condTabItem))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(tabitem.Current.Name);
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I look for every button in the window and it turns out that the new tab is allways at position 4 before minimize, restore and close buttons. I know is not the cleanest solution to incorporate a *magic number* but it does the job.

Here you go! I tested it in VS2015

[image: working :S]

Comment: What does this print out for you?

Comment: c# - Code should work but it doesn't - Stack Overflow
asdf - Google Search
Recibidos - ***@gmail.com - Gmail
Facebook - Entra o regístrate
Tu pizza a domicilio por Internet. Ofertas exclusivas - Telepizza.es
fasdfa+ - Google Search 
which are the tabs I have open for testing this.

Comment: For me it doesn't do anything, the console is black and that's it.

Comment: @user6879072 Try to put a breakpoint. Also I have added `Console.ReadKey()` to stop execution before it exits

Comment: I put a break at foreach. Does this say anything, I haven't used breakpoints and debugging before. https://snag.gy/xXIYe4.jpg